# Change the download path for Chrome/Chromium using Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, express, google-chrome, puppeteer, chromium

Iam using ubuntu 16.04 LTS and working on **scraping** project and trying to download a file using pupeteer But I am unable to change the download location in both chromium/chrome.
I have already tried below option but it is not working:

```
await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: '/tmp'});
```

Even when i enable this in headless:false mode then chromium crashes and in case of headless:true nothing gets downloaded anywhere not even in default location.
Can some one please help me doing that. Please find below my code written in Express

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
var fs = require("fs")
async function downloadCSVFiles(){
console.log("Starting csv download process")
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    defaultViewport: null,
    args: ['--no-sandbox']
})

const page = await browser.newPage()

const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle0'})
await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: '/tmp'});    
const url = 'http://www.sitewithusercredential.com'
await page.goto(url)
await navigationPromise

console.log(page.url());

await page.waitForSelector('form > .row > .login-form > .sign-in-btn')
await page.click('form > .row > .login-form > .sign-in-btn')

await navigationPromise;
console.log(page.url())

 const options = await page.$$('.popOver > .customPopup > div > ul > li')
   
   await options[1].click(); //this will download the file

    await navigationPromise
}
```

Answer (score 4):

At the top of your file, import path:
`const path = require('path')`

Then for the downloadPath in the options you pass into `client.send()`, change it to `path.resolve(__dirname, 'temp)`:

```
await client.send("Page.setDownloadBehavior", {
      behavior: "allow",
      downloadPath: path.resolve(__dirname, 'tmp')
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but i found that this does not work for linux environment. So finally I had to keep the headless:false and then added the display as well as I wanted to execute it in the docker container also later.

Comment: Works in windows environment.